# How do I create this map polygon outline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm quite new to QGIS and want to create a map using this technique

[image]

The map of GB is made up of lines on one layer. Each of the yellow polygons must touch or overlap each other and have the outline of the coast where it meets the lines from the map layer. I would like to end up with a polygon shapefile which would form the basis of an exclusion zone for another program.

I'm looking for tutorial or guide on how this might be achieved. If this is not available then some simple tips on what tools in QGIS to research in order to self teach.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  What particular technique is it you wish to use, your image doesn't give enough information.  As for how that image is created I could only guess a downloaded polygon of GB and what could be a 50km(100km??) grid which has then had the land polygon taken away from the grid (difference tool)

Comment: @Passman Can you clarify what is that please ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give a bit more detail about what in particular you want to be able to do, as it's not obvious from the picture.

Comment: Where did you receive this image from? Is there no description from the source which mentioned how this image was created?

Comment: The original map was from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines and the image I posted was an example of the final product I'm looking for

Comment: You wrote "I would like to end up with a polygon shapefile which would form the basis of an exclusion zone". What area/objects should this polygon shapefile contain?